# Green Function First Order DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having a bit of trouble working out the Green function for $$y' = f(x)$$ when the boundary condition is something like $y(a) = y_0 \neq 0$. I'll do it as though $y(a) = 0$ and at the end modify to $y(a) = y_0$, am I doing something wrong below?

When I want to solve $$\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x),$$ $$a < x < \infty,$$ $$y(a) = 0,$$ using a Green function $$G(x,t)$$ satisfying $$G'(x,t) = \delta(t-x),$$ $$G(a,t) = 0$$ I simply start with $$\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x) = \int_a^\infty f(t) \delta (t - x)dt = \int_a^\infty f(t) G'(x,t)dt = \frac{d}{dx} \int_a^\infty f(t) G(x,t)dt$$ to see $$y(x) = \int_a^\infty f(t) G(x,t)dt.$$

To determing $G$ explicitly I solve $$G'(x,t) = \delta (t - x)$$ which I translate into meaning $$G'(x,t) = 0, x < t \rightarrow G(x,t) = c_1,$$ $$G'(x,t) = 0, t < x \rightarrow G(x,t) = c_2,$$ $$G'(x,t) = \delta (t - x) \rightarrow \int_{t^-}^{t^+}G'(x,t)dx = \int_{t^-}^{t^+}\delta (t - x)dx = 1 \rightarrow G(t^+,t) - G(t^-,t) = 1$$ thus I have to solve $$G(x,t) = c_1, x < t,$$ $$G(x,t) = c_2, t < x,$$ $$G(t^+,t) - G(t^-,t) = 1$$ simultaneously, using the boundary conditions.

Thus, $G(a,t) = 0$ implies $$G(x,t^-) = c_1 = 0, x < t$$ and so $$G(x,t^+) = G(x,t) = c_2 = 1, t < x$$ means that $$G(x,t) = H(x - t)$$ which implies $$y(x) = \int_a^\infty f(t) G(x,t)dt = \int_a^\infty f(t) H(x-t)dt = \int_a^\infty f(x)dx.$$

---

OK the process is exactly the same when $y(a) = y_0 \neq 0$ except the last paragraph, so:

Thus, $G(a,t) = y_0$ implies $$G(x,t^-) = c_1 = y_0, x < t$$ and so $$G(x,t^+) = y_0+1 = y_0 + H(x-t).$$

Now $$y(x) = \int_a^\infty f(t) G(x,t)dt = \int_a^t y_0 f(t) dt + \int_t^\infty (y_0 +H(x-t))f(t) d$$

$$y(x) = \int_a^t y_0 f(t) dt + \int_t^\infty y_0f(t) dt + \int_t^\infty H(x-t))f(t) dt$$

$$y(x) = \int_a^\infty y_0 f(t) dt + \int_a^\infty f(x) dx$$

$$y(x) = (y_0 + 1)\int_a^\infty f(x) dx$$

Is this right, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of the unit step function is a delta function. So you want a function $G(x,t)$ such that, for any fixed $t \in (a,\infty)$,
$\;\;\;$      (a) $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\;G(x,t)=0$ for $x \in (a,t)\cup(t,\infty)$,
$\;\;\;$      (b) $G(x,t)$ has a unit jump in $x$ at $t \in (a,\infty)$,
$\;\;\;$      (c) $G(a,t)=0$.
For a fixed $t \in (a,\infty)$, the desired solution $G(x,t)$ is
$$
   G(x,t) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}0 & x \in (a,t) \\
              1 & x \in (t,\infty)\end{array} \right. .
$$
The Green function solution is
$$
        y(x) = \int_{a}^{\infty}G(x,t)f(t)\,dt = \int_{a}^{x}f(t)\,dt.
$$